# Override decimal ToString() method

Tags: c#, overriding, decimal, number-formatting

I have a decimal datatype with a precision of (18, 8) in my database and even if its value is simply 14.765 it will still get displayed as 14.76500000 when I use Response.Write to return its value into a webpage.

Is it possible to override its default ToString method to return the number in the format `#,###,##0.########` so that it only displays relevant decimal places?

**UPDATE**

I'm assuming that when one outputs number on a page like `<%= item.price %>` (where `item.price` is a number) that the number's ToString method is being called?

I'm trying to avoid having to change every instance where the value is displayed by defaulting the ToString() format somehow.

Comment: A simple search query gave me this: http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzeeb5cd.aspx

Comment: I want to default the way it is presented on all pages 
e.g. I want `<%= item.price %>` (where price is the 18,8 decimal) to look like `14.765` instead of `14.76500000` instead of having to go to everywhere and change it to `<%= item.price.ToString("#,###,##0.########") %>`

Comment: This is a good question, seems like its not possible to do, since nobody has answered it properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't override ToString for **decimal** type since it's a **struct**.

But you can use extension methods to do so:

```
public static class DecimalExtensions
{
      public static string ToString(this decimal some, bool compactFormat)
      {
            if(compactFormat) 
            {
                return some.ToString("#,###,##0.########");
            }
            else
            {
                return some.ToString();
            }
      }
}
```

So now you can do this:

```
string compactedDecimalText = 16.38393m.ToString(true);
```

Comment: Thanks :( I have done this exact thing infact, was just hoping that there was a way to override the default ToString()

Comment: No way, you can't do that for structs.

Answer (score 6):

You don't want to override `ToString()`, you want to call [`ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ebe5aks.aspx) and specify an `IFormatProvider` or a [formatting String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzeeb5cd.aspx)

Comment: Not necessarily. For instance, if you are using a purchased grid solution, overriding ToString is the only option at times.

Comment: and what is a purchased grid? From OP: " when I use Response.Write to return its value into a webpage"

Comment: Ah, I see. It's not related to OP, if he's only using using Response.Write.

Comment: Thanks for the response - however, Im trying to avoid having to change every instance where the value is displayed by defaulting the ToString() format somehow.

Comment: As others have mentioned, you can't override since Decimal is a struct. It seems like you may want to have a design change here. At a minimum, define your format string in a constants file. For example, we display DateTime as a common DTG (date time group). I have the string defined in a consts file and that const string can be passed to a ToString() method or a format specifier for a DataGrid.

Comment: Even if you could override, it would violate "least suprise", since it's expected that an empty ToString() call for all data structures has a nominal/generic/default behavior, not something speicfic to your application domain.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem as you. People wanted decimals to be formatted in crazy custom ways throughout the application.

My first idea was to create a wrapper around Decimal and override the ToString() method.

Although you cannot inherit from Decimal, you can create a type that implicitly casts to and from a Decimal.

This creates a facade in front of Decimal, and gives you a place to write custom formatting logic.

Below is my possible solution, let me know if this works or if this is a horrible idea.

```
public struct Recimal
{

    private decimal _val;
    public Recimal(decimal d) { _val = d; }

    public static implicit operator Recimal(decimal d)
    {
        return new Recimal(d);
    }

    public static implicit operator Decimal(Recimal d)
    {
        return d._val;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        //if negative, show the minus sign to the right of the number
        if (_val < 0)
            return String.Format("{0:0.00;0.00-;}", _val);

        return _val.ToString();
    }

}
```

It works just like a Decimal:

```
        Decimal d = 5;
        Recimal r = -10M;
        Recimal result = r + d;

        //result: 5.00-
        textBox1.Text = result.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `string.Format()` directly on `double`?

Here are some references for the formatting options:

- [Formatting Double](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/)
- [MSDN Numeric Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the response - however, Im trying to avoid having to change every instance where the value is displayed by defaulting the ToString() format somehow.